# Google Static Map Image not working on Tizen Device but on emulator

Tags: c++, google-maps, tizen, google-maps-static-api

I am downloading the static map image from Google for my Tizen App. The code works perfectly fine with the emulator but with the real device it is not working well. It shows blank image

Sample URL we use:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=38.215,35.3454&zoom=13&size=450x250&markers=icon:<markerURL>|shadow:false|38.215,35.3454&sensor=true&style=feature:water|visibility:on|hue:0x0091ff|saturation:39|lightness:-4|gamma:0.84&style=feature:poi|saturation:19|lightness:-5|gamma:0.94&style=feature:road|gamma:0.83|weight:1.1&style=feature:transit|saturation:39|gamma:0.78|hue:0xffcc00|lightness:-16&style=feature:administrative|gamma:0.5&style=feature:road.highway|visibility:on|saturation:-18&style=feature:poi.park|gamma:1.22|lightness:-4|saturation:-43&style=feature:road.arterial|saturation:-49|lightness:42|gamma:0.6.jpg
```

Note that the keys are not used with this URL.

Comment: Define "not working well"

Answer (score 0):

When I go to the URL in your question, I see a 'blank image'.  However when I adjust the zoom level to be slightly more zoomed out, decreasing it from 13 to 10, I see some map.  I think you're just too zoomed in on those coordinates, so seeing a completely blank bit of map.

e.g.
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=38.215,35.3454&zoom=10&size=450x250&markers=icon:%3CmarkerURL%3E|shadow:false|38.215,35.3454&sensor=true&style=feature:water|visibility:on|hue:0x0091ff|saturation:39|lightness:-4|gamma:0.84&style=feature:poi|saturation:19|lightness:-5|gamma:0.94&style=feature:road|gamma:0.83|weight:1.1&style=feature:transit|saturation:39|gamma:0.78|hue:0xffcc00|lightness:-16&style=feature:administrative|gamma:0.5&style=feature:road.highway|visibility:on|saturation:-18&style=feature:poi.park|gamma:1.22|lightness:-4|saturation:-43&style=feature:road.arterial|saturation:-49|lightness:42|gamma:0.6.jpg